# Are questions about automotive history on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Most of the questions here are "my current car is broken?".  I was wondering about including questions about automotive history. Things like "What are the key differences between a model A and Model T ford?".  This might increase visits to the site, as well as attracting more car buffs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Most of the questions here are "my current car is broken?".

Well, yes, they're going to be: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> "What are the key differences between a model A and Model T ford?"

An open-ended question like this is hard to answer definitively.  For example, what makes a difference "key"?

A more specific (and yet still "historical) question could be answered however.  For example, if you were to ask "I can't seem to get a good oil seal on my Model A - were they always known to have poor oil seals?" (a problem similar to one faced by my neighbor: his vintage car *was* always known for poor oil seals so he has drip pans everywhere).

[The chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair), however, has fewer restrictions and is a perfect place to bring up conversational topics or questions.

Comment: I posted [What was the first mass production pickup?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9205) lets see what happens.

Comment: The test question did not receive significant reaction; positive or negative attention. So on topic probably = yes.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, are you asking me to flag it as off-topic?

Comment: No, My question was if auto history was on topic, and there was not a clear rule about it.  Based on response to the question here at meta, and the test question I posted.  I think the answer is that auto history questions are on topic, assuming they are otherwise appropriate.

Comment: Your test question passed the most important hurdle: it was answerable.  "key differences between?" is open to interpretation.  "Which one was first?" has a clear answer.